# directly calculate the MLE of marginal distribution of the observable variable in EM algorithm

Tags: mathematical-statistics

One thing I cannot understand for the EM (Expectation maximization) algorithm, for the observable variable $Y$ and latent variable $Z,$ why don't we directly take MLE (Maximal likelihood estimation) of $Y?$ Since $Y$'s marginal distribution is independent on $Z,$ then we are no need to know the observation of $Z.$

Is the marginal distribution of $Y:f(y|\Theta)$ not easy to calculated? At least for the given examples in the book, we know their marginal distributions.

for example:

1. latent variable: $Z\sim Bernoulli(\pi),$

   observably variable: $(Y|Z=1)\sim Bernoulli(p),\ (Y|Z=0)\sim Bernoulli(q),$

   then we know $f(y|\pi,p,q) = \pi p^y(1-p)^{1-y} + (1-\pi)q^y(1-q)^{1-y}.$
2. latent variable: $P(Z=i) = p_i,$

   observably variable:  $(Y|Z=i)\sim n(\mu_i,\sigma^2_i),$ PDF noted as $n(y|\mu_i,\sigma^2_i).$

   then we know $f(y|p_1\cdots p_n,\mu_1,\cdots\mu_n,\sigma^2_1\cdots,\sigma^2_n) = \sum\limits_ip_i\cdot n(y|\mu_i,\sigma^2_i).$

the marginal distributions of $Y$ are all known.

Comment: do you mean when the density of  is tractable such as latent variable is Bernoulli (see my update), EM is meanless?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that the likelihood can be numerically computed in a manageable $\text O(n)$ time does not imply that the derivation of the associated maximum likelihood is feasible by analytical or standard numerical means. For instance, this representation of [the (log-)likelihood surface of a two parameter mixture model](https://xianblog.wordpress.com/2017/11/28/sliced-wasserstein-estimation-of-mixtures/) exhibits the presence of at least three local modes, likely to confuse numerical methods. EM provides at least the guarantee that the endpoint of the sequence is a local mode.

[image]

Comment: is it same story here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/94559/why-is-optimizing-a-mixture-of-gaussian-directly-computationally-hard

Comment: @user6703592: yes indeed, see [my more detailed answer there.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/129858/7224).